# Making sense of !address -summary for managed allocations

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, heap-memory, windbg, sos

I am  trying to understand how !address -summary report managed allocations. I have following code to try to test it out. I basically change the size of array and then attach windbg to inspect results for !address -summary

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
int size = 2000;
            var something = new byte[size];
            for (int i = 0; i < something.Length; i++)
            {
                something[i] = 10;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Attach Windbg now");
            Console.Read();

    // not sure if its needed but have it so that this object is still referenced and optimizations don't remove it proactively
            for (int i = 0; i < something.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(something[i]);
            }
        }
```

With a size = 50000

```
--- Usage Summary ---------------- RgnCount ----------- Total Size -------- %ofBusy %ofTotal
Free                                     53     7fff`e1546000 ( 128.000 Tb)          100.00%
<unknown>                                61        0`18a1d000 ( 394.113 Mb)  80.32%    0.00%
Image                                   163        0`031da000 (  49.852 Mb)  10.16%    0.00%
MappedFile                               12        0`019f8000 (  25.969 Mb)   5.29%    0.00%
Stack                                    12        0`01000000 (  16.000 Mb)   3.26%    0.00%
Heap                                     22        0`002f3000 (   2.949 Mb)   0.60%    0.00%
Other                                     8        0`001bf000 (   1.746 Mb)   0.36%    0.00%
TEB                                       4        0`00008000 (  32.000 kb)   0.01%    0.00%
PEB                                       1        0`00001000 (   4.000 kb)   0.00%    0.00%

--- Type Summary (for busy) ------ RgnCount ----------- Total Size -------- %ofBusy %ofTotal
MEM_PRIVATE                             101        0`19d0b000 ( 413.043 Mb)  84.18%    0.00%
MEM_IMAGE                               163        0`031da000 (  49.852 Mb)  10.16%    0.00%
MEM_MAPPED                               19        0`01bc5000 (  27.770 Mb)   5.66%    0.00%

--- State Summary ---------------- RgnCount ----------- Total Size -------- %ofBusy %ofTotal
MEM_FREE                                 53     7fff`e1546000 ( 128.000 Tb)          100.00%
MEM_RESERVE                              51        0`1aec5000 ( 430.770 Mb)  87.79%    0.00%
MEM_COMMIT                              232        0`03be5000 (  59.895 Mb)  12.21%    0.00%

--- Protect Summary (for commit) - RgnCount ----------- Total Size -------- %ofBusy %ofTotal
PAGE_EXECUTE_READ                        24        0`0262d000 (  38.176 Mb)   7.78%    0.00%
PAGE_READONLY                            71        0`00dfb000 (  13.980 Mb)   2.85%    0.00%
PAGE_WRITECOPY                           31        0`00417000 (   4.090 Mb)   0.83%    0.00%
PAGE_READWRITE                           81        0`00335000 (   3.207 Mb)   0.65%    0.00%
PAGE_EXECUTE_WRITECOPY                    3        0`00043000 ( 268.000 kb)   0.05%    0.00%
PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE                   15        0`00016000 (  88.000 kb)   0.02%    0.00%
PAGE_READWRITE|PAGE_GUARD                 5        0`00015000 (  84.000 kb)   0.02%    0.00%
PAGE_EXECUTE                              2        0`00003000 (  12.000 kb)   0.00%    0.00%

--- Largest Region by Usage ----------- Base Address -------- Region Size ----------
Free                                      0`7fff0000     7ff5`7f760000 ( 127.959 Tb)
<unknown>                                 0`02e62000        0`0ffde000 ( 255.867 Mb)
Image                                  7ffd`0ab5d000        0`010e4000 (  16.891 Mb)
MappedFile                                0`0150c000        0`01234000 (  18.203 Mb)
Stack                                     0`1ba90000        0`003f9000 (   3.973 Mb)
Heap                                      0`02741000        0`00101000 (   1.004 Mb)
Other                                     0`011b0000        0`00181000 (   1.504 Mb)
TEB                                    7ff5`ff928000        0`00002000 (   8.000 kb)
PEB                                    7ff5`ff926000        0`00001000 (   4.000 kb)
```

this is how it looks in !dumpheap -stat output

```
00007ffd0ad95740        4        50609 System.Byte[]
```

this is how it looks in !EEHeap -gc output

```
Number of GC Heaps: 1
generation 0 starts at 0x0000000002ec1030
generation 1 starts at 0x0000000002ec1018
generation 2 starts at 0x0000000002ec1000
ephemeral segment allocation context: ephemeral segment allocation context: none
none
 segment     begin allocated  size
0000000002ec0000  0000000002ec1000  0000000002ed3fe8  0x12fe8(77800)
Large object heap starts at 0x0000000012ec1000
 segment     begin allocated  size
0000000012ec0000  0000000012ec1000  0000000012ec9720  0x8720(34592)
Total Size:              Total Size:              Size: 0x1b708 (112392) bytesSize: 0x1b708 (112392) bytes.
.
------------------------------
------------------------------
GC Heap Size:            GC Heap Size:            Size: 0x1b708 (112392) bytesSize: 0x1b708 (112392) bytes.
```

**With a size = 2000**

```
0:003> !address -summary
Mapping file section regions...
Mapping module regions...
Mapping PEB regions...
Mapping TEB and stack regions...
Mapping heap regions...
Mapping page heap regions...
Mapping other regions...
Mapping stack trace database regions...
Mapping activation context regions...

--- Usage Summary ---------------- RgnCount ----------- Total Size -------- %ofBusy %ofTotal
Free                                     50     7fff`e1941000 ( 128.000 Tb)          100.00%
<unknown>                                57        0`1861b000 ( 390.105 Mb)  80.16%    0.00%
Image                                   163        0`031da000 (  49.852 Mb)  10.24%    0.00%
MappedFile                               12        0`019f8000 (  25.969 Mb)   5.34%    0.00%
Stack                                    12        0`01000000 (  16.000 Mb)   3.29%    0.00%
Heap                                     22        0`002fa000 (   2.977 Mb)   0.61%    0.00%
Other                                     8        0`001bf000 (   1.746 Mb)   0.36%    0.00%
TEB                                       4        0`00008000 (  32.000 kb)   0.01%    0.00%
PEB                                       1        0`00001000 (   4.000 kb)   0.00%    0.00%

--- Type Summary (for busy) ------ RgnCount ----------- Total Size -------- %ofBusy %ofTotal
MEM_PRIVATE                              97        0`19910000 ( 409.063 Mb)  84.05%    0.00%
MEM_IMAGE                               163        0`031da000 (  49.852 Mb)  10.24%    0.00%
MEM_MAPPED                               19        0`01bc5000 (  27.770 Mb)   5.71%    0.00%

--- State Summary ---------------- RgnCount ----------- Total Size -------- %ofBusy %ofTotal
MEM_FREE                                 50     7fff`e1941000 ( 128.000 Tb)          100.00%
MEM_RESERVE                              50        0`1aadc000 ( 426.859 Mb)  87.71%    0.00%
MEM_COMMIT                              229        0`03bd3000 (  59.824 Mb)  12.29%    0.00%

--- Protect Summary (for commit) - RgnCount ----------- Total Size -------- %ofBusy %ofTotal
PAGE_EXECUTE_READ                        24        0`0262d000 (  38.176 Mb)   7.84%    0.00%
PAGE_READONLY                            71        0`00dfb000 (  13.980 Mb)   2.87%    0.00%
PAGE_WRITECOPY                           31        0`00417000 (   4.090 Mb)   0.84%    0.00%
PAGE_READWRITE                           79        0`00326000 (   3.148 Mb)   0.65%    0.00%
PAGE_EXECUTE_WRITECOPY                    3        0`00043000 ( 268.000 kb)   0.05%    0.00%
PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE                   15        0`00016000 (  88.000 kb)   0.02%    0.00%
PAGE_READWRITE|PAGE_GUARD                 4        0`00012000 (  72.000 kb)   0.01%    0.00%
PAGE_EXECUTE                              2        0`00003000 (  12.000 kb)   0.00%    0.00%

--- Largest Region by Usage ----------- Base Address -------- Region Size ----------
Free                                      0`7fff0000     7ff5`7f7a0000 ( 127.959 Tb)
<unknown>                                 0`02912000        0`0ffee000 ( 255.930 Mb)
Image                                  7ffd`0ab5d000        0`010e4000 (  16.891 Mb)
MappedFile                                0`0102c000        0`01234000 (  18.203 Mb)
Stack                                     0`1b350000        0`003f9000 (   3.973 Mb)
Heap                                      0`022a8000        0`00101000 (   1.004 Mb)
Other                                     0`00cd0000        0`00181000 (   1.504 Mb)
TEB                                    7ff5`ff968000        0`00002000 (   8.000 kb)
PEB                                    7ff5`ff967000        0`00001000 (   4.000 kb)
```

this is how it looks in !dumpheap -stat output

```
00007ffd0ad95740        4         2609 System.Byte[]
```

here is the ouput of !EEHeap -gc

```
Number of GC Heaps: 1
generation 0 starts at 0x0000000002bd1030
generation 1 starts at 0x0000000002bd1018
generation 2 starts at 0x0000000002bd1000
ephemeral segment allocation context: none
 segment     begin allocated  size
0000000002bd0000  0000000002bd1000  0000000002bd7fe8  0x6fe8(28648)
Large object heap starts at 0x0000000012bd1000
 segment     begin allocated  size
0000000012bd0000  0000000012bd1000  0000000012bd9720  0x8720(34592)
Total Size:              Size: 0xf708 (63240) bytes.
------------------------------
GC Heap Size:            Size: 0xf708 (63240) bytes.
```

**When I change the array size to 5000000 this is what I see in !dumpheap -stat**

```
00007ffd0ad95740        4      5000609 System.Byte[]
```

Here is output of !EEHeap -gc command

```
Number of GC Heaps: 1
generation 0 starts at 0x0000000002bd1030
generation 1 starts at 0x0000000002bd1018
generation 2 starts at 0x0000000002bd1000
ephemeral segment allocation context: none
 segment     begin allocated  size
0000000002bd0000  0000000002bd1000  0000000002bd7fe8  0x6fe8(28648)
Large object heap starts at 0x0000000012bd1000
 segment     begin allocated  size
0000000012bd0000  0000000012bd1000  000000001309e298  0x4cd298(5034648)
Total Size:              Size: 0x4d4280 (5063296) bytes.
------------------------------
GC Heap Size:            Size: 0x4d4280 (5063296) bytes.
```

And address summary is below

```
0:003> !address -summary


Mapping file section regions...
Mapping module regions...
Mapping PEB regions...
Mapping TEB and stack regions...
Mapping heap regions...
Mapping page heap regions...
Mapping other regions...
Mapping stack trace database regions...
Mapping activation context regions...

--- Usage Summary ---------------- RgnCount ----------- Total Size -------- %ofBusy %ofTotal
Free                                     50     7fff`e153a000 ( 128.000 Tb)          100.00%
<unknown>                                61        0`18a1d000 ( 394.113 Mb)  80.31%    0.00%
Image                                   163        0`031da000 (  49.852 Mb)  10.16%    0.00%
MappedFile                               12        0`019f8000 (  25.969 Mb)   5.29%    0.00%
Stack                                    12        0`01000000 (  16.000 Mb)   3.26%    0.00%
Heap                                     22        0`002ff000 (   2.996 Mb)   0.61%    0.00%
Other                                     8        0`001bf000 (   1.746 Mb)   0.36%    0.00%
TEB                                       4        0`00008000 (  32.000 kb)   0.01%    0.00%
PEB                                       1        0`00001000 (   4.000 kb)   0.00%    0.00%

--- Type Summary (for busy) ------ RgnCount ----------- Total Size -------- %ofBusy %ofTotal
MEM_PRIVATE                             101        0`19d17000 ( 413.090 Mb)  84.18%    0.00%
MEM_IMAGE                               163        0`031da000 (  49.852 Mb)  10.16%    0.00%
MEM_MAPPED                               19        0`01bc5000 (  27.770 Mb)   5.66%    0.00%

--- State Summary ---------------- RgnCount ----------- Total Size -------- %ofBusy %ofTotal
MEM_FREE                                 50     7fff`e153a000 ( 128.000 Tb)          100.00%
MEM_RESERVE                              51        0`1aa05000 ( 426.020 Mb)  86.82%    0.00%
MEM_COMMIT                              232        0`040b1000 (  64.691 Mb)  13.18%    0.00%

--- Protect Summary (for commit) - RgnCount ----------- Total Size -------- %ofBusy %ofTotal
PAGE_EXECUTE_READ                        24        0`0262d000 (  38.176 Mb)   7.78%    0.00%
PAGE_READONLY                            71        0`00e1d000 (  14.113 Mb)   2.88%    0.00%
PAGE_READWRITE                           81        0`007df000 (   7.871 Mb)   1.60%    0.00%
PAGE_WRITECOPY                           31        0`00417000 (   4.090 Mb)   0.83%    0.00%
PAGE_EXECUTE_WRITECOPY                    3        0`00043000 ( 268.000 kb)   0.05%    0.00%
PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE                   15        0`00016000 (  88.000 kb)   0.02%    0.00%
PAGE_READWRITE|PAGE_GUARD                 5        0`00015000 (  84.000 kb)   0.02%    0.00%
PAGE_EXECUTE                              2        0`00003000 (  12.000 kb)   0.00%    0.00%

--- Largest Region by Usage ----------- Base Address -------- Region Size ----------
Free                                      0`7fff0000     7ff5`7f7d0000 ( 127.959 Tb)
<unknown>                                 0`02be2000        0`0ffee000 ( 255.930 Mb)
Image                                  7ffd`0ab5d000        0`010e4000 (  16.891 Mb)
MappedFile                                0`0134c000        0`01214000 (  18.078 Mb)
Stack                                     0`1b760000        0`003f9000 (   3.973 Mb)
Heap                                      0`0265d000        0`00101000 (   1.004 Mb)
Other                                     0`00fd0000        0`00181000 (   1.504 Mb)
TEB                                    7ff5`ff996000        0`00002000 (   8.000 kb)
PEB                                    7ff5`ff99e000        0`00001000 (   4.000 kb)
```

The output of dumpheap and eeheap totally makes sense. I don't understand where these managed allocation should be displayed in !address -summary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try the following code, which allocates 20 MB:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Attach Windbg now");
        Console.ReadLine();

        int size = 20000000;
        var something = new byte[size];

        Console.WriteLine("Look again");
        Console.ReadLine();

// not sure if its needed but have it so that this object is still referenced and optimizations don't remove it proactively
        something[0] = 1;
    }
```

Right at the beginning my machine shows

```
<unknown>    49        0`19502000 ( 405.008 Mb)  82.39%    0.00%
MEM_RESERVE  45        0`1b0d4000 ( 432.828 Mb)  88.05%    0.01%
MEM_COMMIT  240        0`03ac0000 (  58.750 Mb)  11.95%    0.00%
```

in the output of `!address -summary`.

Now do a

```
.loadby sos clr    
bp kernel32!VirtualAlloc
g
```

and press Enter in the console application. It will hit the breakpoint and you will see

```
0:000> k
Child-SP          RetAddr           Call Site
00000000`001ce2b8 000007fe`f77c265a KERNEL32!VirtualAlloc
...
00000000`001ce5f0 000007fe`f77c7ece clr!WKS::GCHeap::Alloc+0x348
00000000`001ce640 000007fe`981600f7 clr!JIT_NewArr1+0x49e
...

0:000> !clrstack
OS Thread Id: 0x5c4 (0)
        Child SP               IP Call Site
00000000001ce778 0000000076cb5c68 [HelperMethodFrame: 00000000001ce778] 
00000000001ce8f0 000007fe981600f7 ManagedVirtualAlloc.Program.Main(System.String[])
00000000001cec30 000007fef7829e03 [GCFrame: 00000000001cec30]
```

So you can see that from the Main method the .NET runtime tries to allocate virtual memory to fit the new byte array (as indicated by `JIT_NewArr1`).

However, looking at the parameters passed to VirtualAlloc() (note that `kb` is misleading for 64 bit), we can see

```
0:000> r
...
rcx=0000000012392000 // address of an already reserved memory region
rdx=000000000130b000 // size: 19968000
 r8=0000000000001000 // MEM_COMMIT
 r9=0000000000000004 // PAGE_READWRITE
...

0:000> kb; *** Warning: misleading arguments for 64 bit!
RetAddr           : Args to Child                                                           : Call Site
000007fe`f77c265a : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`001ce369 000007fe`00000000 : KERNEL32!VirtualAlloc
```

we see that it specifies an address which was reserved before and shall now be committed. After the call (enter `g`), we see that some (~ 20 MB) reserved memory has been converted to committed memory while the `<unknown>` amount is still the same.

```
<unknown>     49        0`19502000 ( 405.008 Mb)  82.39%    0.00%
MEM_RESERVE   45        0`19dc1000 ( 413.754 Mb)  84.17%    0.00%
MEM_COMMIT   238        0`04dd3000 (  77.824 Mb)  15.83%    0.00%
```

Conclusion:

.NET reserves a lot of memory in advance. That memory will already show up as `<unused>` right after starting the application. It will then work with that reserved and committed memory if possible, so not every single allocation results in a new VirtualAlloc() call.

Some more internals:

We also see that the .NET framework is quite clever: it allocated only 19968000 bytes instead of 20000000 bytes, because it was able reuse some bytes of a memory block which already was in committed state. Looking at the pointers:

```
VirtualAlloc pointer: 0x0000000012392000
"something" variable: 0x0000000012389710
```

The something variable points to a memory region in front of the memory block returned by the VirtualAlloc() call.

Comment: Thanks. I wish I could have voted up 10 times for very nice explaination

Comment: I had to update my answer due to misleading kb information on 64 bit. But the conclusion is the same.

Answer (score 3):

The managed allocations take place in segments allocated by the CLR using the VirtualAlloc API.  They are reported under the "unknown" section.

Comment: with 50000 unknown category is showing size of 394.113 Mb. 
with  5000000 unknown category is still showing size of 394.113 Mb. Shouldn't it go go up then?

Comment: Segments are reserved by the CLR when it initializes.  Portions of the segments are then committed as necessary as objects are allocated.  If your 5,000,000 objects fit in the segments already allocated, then the unknown category won't increase.